# Uploading asset to S3 isn't working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to upload a css file and a js file to S3 and use them as static resources. If I upload them via web from S3 page, it works. But if I upload via a python script, it uploads the files, but I can't get the css seems not working at all.

Here is my python code,

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('sample.css', 'mybucket', 'sample_dir/sample.css', {'ACL': 'public-read'})
```

Comment: The console automatically sets the `Content-Type:` for many uploads (should probably be `text/css`) but you don't appear to be setting it, so the browser may be refusing to *use* the css even if it downloads successfully (check browser dev tools console).

Comment: Thanks, you are right.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: I already posted it, but your code is most welcomed. Please do :)

Comment: It's customary to post your own answer when you solve the problem independently, but typically you will see notes offering the person providing the hint that led you to a solution the option to post an answer.  In this case, since I provided you with the theoretical resolution but you provided the actual code, I guess it could go either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notable condition here is that files uploaded through the console are correctly used by the browser, but files uploaded through the API are not.

The AWS/S3 console, by default, automatically sets the `Content-Type:` for many uploaded file types, (for CSS, this should probably be `text/css`)... but the API requires it be set by your code.

But, you don't appear to be setting it, so the browser may be refusing to use the css, even if it downloads successfully, because the `Content-Type:` response header contains an unexpected value.

(The browser dev tools/console should show an error or warning to confirm this).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution.

Answer (score 4):

Mentioning file type solved this issue.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('sample.css', 'mybucket', 'sample_dir/sample.css', {'ACL': 'public-read','public-read','ContentType': 'text/css'})
```